# thumbpdf support for latexmk

Tags: latexmk, thumbpdf

I would like to use [thumbpdf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/thumbpdf) in my document and [latexmk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) as build system. When I compile my document, I get following output:

> Latexmk: Missing input file: 'document.tpt' from line
>     'Package thumbpdf Warning: Thumbnail data file `document.tpt' not found.'

Test document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thumbpdf}
\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

Compile with `latexmk -pdf document`.

Is there any possibility to quickly add support for thumbpdf to latexmk or is thumbpdf outdated, because PDF readers such as Acrobat Reader generate the thumbnails by themselves?

Based on [example rc files](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/pdflatexmkrc), I discovered following entry for the `.latexmkrc` file:

```
#add support for thumbpdf
add_cus_dep('pdf', 'tpt', 0, 'thumbpdf');
sub thumbpdf {
    system( "thumbpdf \"$_[0].pdf\"" );
}
```

This creates, however, an endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines to an rc file for `latexmk`:

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O %S && thumbpdf %Z%R';
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'tpt'} = '^% Date: ';
$clean_ext .= ' tpt';
```

(The form for the command line in `$pdflatex` is correct for a UNIX like system, e.g., linux and OS-X, but may need alteration on MS-Windows.)

Comment: Doesn't that always execute thumbpdf even if pdflatex is called multiple times?

Comment: Yes, and that is a disadvantage because thumbpdf runs much slower than pdflatex.  What would be best would be to do a normal run (without invoking thumbpdf), then do postprocessing by a run of thumbpdf and then an extra run of pdflatex.  At present, latexmk doesn't give any simple way of doing that.  But it would be sufficient to write a script that invokes latexmk and then runs thumbpdf and pdflatex.  However, is there really any need for thumbpdf given that modern previewers that support thumbnails also generate them themselves?